# How to run a script without closing the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I have a script in file `bla.sh` and it is executable. When I **click** on it, the script is executed and the window is closed. I'd like **the window to stay open**.

Something like command `cmd /k** command` in Windows.

P.S. I **don't** want to use `pause`, but I want to able to write more commands after the script was executed.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Put `$SHELL` at the end of your script:

[image]

A small flaw: since `gnome-terminal` isn't running the `bash` as it's shell, it will regard it as an application and *display a warning* about it when you try to close the terminal:

```
There is still a process running in this terminal
Closing the terminal will kill it.
```

I've found no nice way to hide this warning. If you want, you can disable it entirely by running:

```
gconftool --set /apps/gnome-terminal/global/confirm_window_close --type boolean false
```

This doesn't happen if you're using `xterm` instead of gnome-terminal; should it bother you.

Comment: You can use `exec $SHELL` instead of just `$SHELL` to make the warning go away without changing settings.

Comment: But this solution creates an extra shell / process. Can this be avoided?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, no. The problem is that you lose your handle on standard IO once the first bash process is finished, so you would have to do some trickery with a daemon that passes on these handles, which would then be more error-prone and annoying.

Comment: On my system, `echo $SHELL` shows that the SHELL variable contains `/bin/bash`. Therefore, using `bash` in place of `$SHELL` is identical. Also, I've determined that all 3 of these at the end will keep the terminal open: `bash`, `eval bash`, `exec bash`, but only the latter, `exec bash`, will then allow you to close the terminal without it warning you a process is still running. Therefore, the best to use is `exec bash` or `exec $SHELL`, as @AndreaCorbellini says in his comment above.

Comment: I made this an answer, since it should stand on its own as an answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal/1209836#1209836.

Comment: It helped, caused to open a configuration window offering a combo to keep open.

Answer (score 19):

Using Gnome Terminal

Using gnome-terminal appending ;bash at the end of the command string and calling the script with -c option works. For example:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ~/script.sh;bash"
```

This does the following:

1. opens gnome-terminal
2. executes the script script.sh
3. shows the bash prompt after the script has finished.

You can exit the gnome-terminal window by closing the window or type exit at the bash prompt. Or you can type more commands as requested.

Comment: `-e` is deprecated, so what do we do now? `# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
`

Comment: This is the only solution that I could get to work (Ubuntu 20.04), however it seems to fail if I add more commands in between, i.e. script.sh;command;bash. Any idea why or how I  should add more commands in between?

Answer (score 18):

If you have access to the script, you may also add the following code at the end:

```
read
```

That code will wait for an input before closing, so the terminal will stay open until you press Enter.

Comment: I often use `bash` at the end, but `read` allows me to close the window just with `ctrl+c` or `enter`, instead of `ctrl+shift+w` or `alt+f4`. This is convenient when you iterate rapidly on your script.

Answer (score 10):

Use `bash`'s `--init-file` option with a temporary pipe:

```
bash --init-file <(echo './<script_name>')
```

Ex:

```
bash --init-file <(echo './bla.sh')
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `<()` and how do I google this?

Comment: `()` is `Process substitution`. `<(cmd)` creates a temp file (actually a FIFO) with the stdout of the `cmd` as its contents. For example, `cat <(echo Hi)` would just dump the o/p of `echo Hi` in a FIFO and feed the FIFO's file descriptor as input to `cat`

Comment: Useful google search: ["linux terminal left angle bracket parentheses"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQjtThW2lDxjPiOgs_I37GTtiOD_Q%3A1581443425013&ei=YelCXscvhe6xBaWPsNgB&q=linux+terminal+left+angle+bracket+parentheses&oq=linux+terminal+left+angle+bracket+parentheses&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3803.11094..11308...0.1..0.174.4843.0j35......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30j0j35i39j0i131i273j0i20i263j33i22i29i30j33i10j33i160j33i299.q94aCL5CUoo&ved=0ahUKEwiH5NHsh8rnAhUFd6wKHaUHDBsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: And some results: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283374/what-does-the-left-chevron-triangle-bracket-do and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators

Answer (score 8):

If you are using [`xterm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xterm.1.html) use `-hold`.

Comment: additionally, if you use konsole `--hold` can work, note the 2 dashes as a single one makes each letter interpret as its own argument

Answer (score 3):

Using `xterm` and appending `;bash` at the end of the command string works. For example:

```
xterm -e "bash ~/script.sh;bash"
```

This does the following:

1. opens xterm
2. executes the script `script.sh`
3. shows the bash prompt after the script has finished.

You can exit the xterm window by closing the window or type `exit` at the bash prompt. Or you can type more commands as requested.

Answer (score 3):

### TLDR;

Use `exec bash;` or `exec $SHELL;` at the end of a command to keep the terminal open after running the command.

### Details and sample test code

There isn't an answer showing `exec bash` as the right answer, but there should be, so here it is. This answer is borrowed in part from [@Karsvo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/176249/327339), [@Stefano Palazo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20353/327339), and @Andrea Corbellini's comment under Stefano's answer.

On my system (this was last tested and checked on Ubuntu 20.04), `echo $SHELL` shows that the SHELL variable contains `/bin/bash`. `which bash` shows that the `bash` executable is located in `/usr/bin/bash`, however. BUT, `/user/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` are identical executables, as proven by having the same `sha256sum`:

```bash
$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash

$ sha256sum $(which bash)
04a484f27a4b485b28451923605d9b528453d6c098a5a5112bec859fb5f2eea9  /usr/bin/bash

$ sha256sum $SHELL
04a484f27a4b485b28451923605d9b528453d6c098a5a5112bec859fb5f2eea9  /bin/bash
```

Therefore, using `bash` in place of `$SHELL` is identical. Also, I've determined that all 3 of these at the end will keep the terminal open: `bash`, `eval bash`, `exec bash`, **but only the latter, `exec bash`, will then allow you to close the terminal without it warning you a process is still running. Therefore, the best to use is `exec bash` or `exec $SHELL`, as @AndreaCorbellini says in his comment.**

#### Test 1: this will work as expected

Here's what this might look like in a use-case of having a script to open up two new `gnome-terminal` tabs already `cd`ed into your `~/some_dir` directory:

Add to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
open_default_tabs() {
    gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -ic "cd ~/some_dir; exec bash;"
    gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -ic "cd ~/some_dir; exec bash;"
}
```

OR: again, you can use `exec $SHELL` here instead as well:

```bash
open_default_tabs() {
    gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -ic "cd ~/some_dir; exec $SHELL;"
    gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -ic "cd ~/some_dir; exec $SHELL;"
}
```

Then in any gnome-terminal already open, re-source your `~/.bashrc` file with `. ~/.bashrc`, then run this command with:

```bash
open_default_tabs
```

...and you'll see your original gnome-terminal tab plus two new tabs, with both of the two new tabs already `cd`ed into the `~/some_dir` directory.

If you delete the `exec bash;` or `exec $SHELL;` portion from the end of each of the commands above, however, then re-source your `~/.bashrc` file with `. ~/.bashrc`, then run the `open_default_tabs` command again, you'll see that the tabs flicker open then immediately close. All you'll see is a couple quick flashes. The `exec bash;` or `exec $SHELL;` part at the end is required to keep these new tabs open.

#### Test 2: this proves that `exec bash;` works. BUT, the behavior regarding `gnome-terminal` isn't quite as expected. To solve that, see my more-complicated answer and work-around [in my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563).

In `test.sh`:

```bash
gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -ic "cd ~/some_dir; exec bash;"
gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -ic "cd ~/some_dir; exec bash;"
```

Ensure `some_dir` exists, and make `test.sh` executable:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/some_dir
chmod +x test.sh
```

Run it:

```bash
./test.sh
```

Notice the two windows (not tabs, in this case, due to a problem in `gnome-terminal`) which were just opened *stay open*. Delete `exec bash;` above and you'll see they don't--they instantly close--so fast you won't even see them open. This proves `exec bash;` is working perfectly. The `gnome-terminal` behavior isn't quite as expected, but that has nothing to do with `exec bash;`, which works just fine. Again, see [my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563) for a full work-around to the problem specific to `gnome-terminal` in this case.

### Related:

1. Here's why I REALLY needed this information! This is my "other answer" I mention above: [Open Terminal with multiple tabs and execute application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563)

Comment: `exec bash` seems promising, but it only seems to work as described if the script has been executed in terminal via file dialog, not if the terminal was open to begin with and `./path/to/script.sh` was typed. Currently I’m using a combination of [`readlink`](https://askubuntu.com/a/729918/392027) and checking `$COLORTERM` to check if `exit` would close the terminal window, and use `exec bash` only in this case.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I've massively updated my answer. What you are experiencing is a problem with `gnome-terminal`, _not_ a problem with `exec bash;` at the end of a command, which works just fine. Please see my Test 1 and Test 2 sections added to my answer above, and [my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563) for the fix to your `gnome-terminal` problem.

Comment: I’ve read both answers now, but concerning the `exec bash` behavior when executing a shell script via file terminal, the first answer only links to the second one, and the second answer doesn’t seem to address this in detail; instead it talks more about setting titles by calling `gnome-terminal`. Not sure what exactly I should be looking at. My workaround works just fine, anyway. Minor nitpick: _“as proven by having the same `sha256sum`”_ — or more directly: `[[ '/bin/bash' -ef '/usr/bin/bash' ]]` or `[[ "$(readlink -f '/bin/bash')" = "$(readlink -f '/usr/bin/bash')" ]]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
xterm -e bash --rcfile bla.sh
```

This will run the script in a new window, and even give you control of the window after it is finished.

However the new window will not load `~/.bashrc` as normal, since we ran `bla.sh` instead. This can be remedied by putting

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

at the top of `bla.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that gnome-terminal is a bit bad on doing this, xterm is more serene to do this task without poping up questions. For instance, I executed a command "date" and it was COVERED BY A BLUE POPUP from gnome-terminal saying that the child process exit fine, impeding me to see the output of date.

Gnome-terminal should add a menu "Disable all terminal messages"

**IMPORTANT**: you should be in the execution directory where all dependences are found from '.'

Type this, and the terminal will be kept in a new process:

```
xterm -fa Monospace -fs 10 -e "bash -c 'mycommand arg1 arg2 argn';bash" &
```