# Stop terminal from closing automatically when a shell script is run

Tags: 12.04, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run script and don't close a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-script-and-dont-close-a-terminal)

Whenever I try to run a shell script (with syntax errors) in the terminal on Ubuntu 12.04, the terminal opens and then quickly closes, so that I can't even see the command-line output. Is it possible to stop the terminal window from closing in this case?