# Launching php script through comman line - keeping terminal window open after execution

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scripts, gnome-terminal, php

Oh, my girlfriend really likes it when I launch php scripts!  There's something special about them, she says ...

Thus, I coded this script to run throught the CLI (Command Line Interface) - so it's running locally, not on a web server.

It launches just fine through right click > open > run in terminal
but closes right after execution. ****Is there a way to keep the terminal window open?**

Of course I can launch it through a terminal window - which would stay open - but I'm looking for a one click action. With bash scripts I use `$SHELL` but that didn't work (see code below).

So far, the only thing I came up with is `sleep(10);` which gives me 10 seconds for my girl to check the output.  I'd rather close the terminal window manually, though.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

    echo "Hello World \n";

    # wait before closing terminal window
    sleep(10);

    # the following line doesn't work
    $SHELL;

?>
```

*(PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 14:57:54) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a script without closing the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal)

Comment: The question is not a duplicate.  The link provides a solution for bash scripts.  In the above case it is a php script ... adding $SHELL doesn't work.

Comment: You are mixing bash and php code. The correct way would be `system("\$SHELL");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Salem](https://askubuntu.com/users/33871/salem) said in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275746/launching-php-script-through-comman-line-keeping-terminal-window-open-after-ex#comment346577_275746), *you are mixing bash and php code*. You can use [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) php function to prevent this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

    echo "Hello World \n";

    # prevent to close terminal using php
    shell_exec('$SHELL');

?>
```

> [string **shell_exec** ( string *$cmd* )](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string.

[image: shell_exec]

Comment: Thanks for leading this to an officially answered question :)