# Run command on another(new) terminal window

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, execute-command

How to run any command in another terminal window?

Example: I opened one terminal window and if I run command like `apropos editor`, then it run and out-puts on that window. **But I want to run same command on another terminal window (new window) instead on present window from *first terminal*.**

**Further clarification**:

I need `suggest-command <command>` that open new terminal window and run mentioned `<command>` in that (newly opened) window. (where `suggest-command` is example of suggestion of command.)

How to do that?

Comment: Right-Click on the terminal icon and click on "Open New Terminal".

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a lamen, but that's what I understood from your question.

Comment: gnome-terminal right?

Comment: While opening a new terminal may solve your problem, you might also wish to simply use nohup, re-direct the output, and put your editor in the background. `nohup apropos editor &> /dev/null &`

Comment: I also do not understand: why not to open a new terminal?

Comment: because it might have to be done by a cron job, or another robot program.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This might be what you run:

```bash
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "bash -c \"!!; exec bash\""
```

In older versions, -e and -x were used:

```bash
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"!!; exec bash\""
# or
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "!!; bash"
```

It opens gnome-terminal with your last command (`!!`) executed and it **stays** open with the command output in the shell, even with an interactive command like `top` or `less`...

In your case its:

```bash
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "bash -c \"apropos editor; exec bash\""
```

or in older versions:

```bash
gnome-terminal -c "bash -c \"apropos editor; exec bash\""
# or
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "apropos editor; bash"
```

Comment: A little bit shorter `gnome-terminal -x sh -c "!!; bash"`

Comment: `Option “-x” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal`

Comment: Under Xubuntu, the terminal command is `xfce4-terminal`, see it's documentation for more details: https://docs.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal/command-line

Comment: Even simpler: `gnome-terminal -- bash -c "YOURCOMMAND ; exec bash"`

Answer (score 13):

Each terminal is even a program that you can launch as any other program,
 with `&` to put in background, giving a list of arguments and so on.

Which terminal to use it depends first from the availability of the system that you are using (if they are installed or not), after from their peculiarity and then from your personal taste.

```
  konsole   --hold -e "ls" &  
  xterm      -hold -e "ls" &  
  gnome-terminal   -e "ls" & ...
```

Note the differences between **`-hold`** of `xterm` and **`--hold`** of `konsole`.

Each realization has **different options** that you have to check with the help.
Even the help can be invoked in different way. 
You can find that `man konsole` doesn't function and so you have to ask directly to the executable with `--help`.

This is a list of terminal you can search on your system

```
aterm          - AfterStep terminal with transparency support
gnome-terminal - default terminal for GNOME
guake          - A dropdown terminal for GNOME
konsole        - default terminal for KDE
Kuake          - a dropdown terminal for KDE
mrxvt          - Multi-tabbed rxvt clone
rxvt           - for the X Window System (and, in the form of a Cygwin port, 
                 for Windows) 
rxvt-unicode   - rxvt clone with unicode support
xfce4-terminal - default terminal for Xfce desktop 
                 environment with dropdown support
Terminator     - is a GPL terminal emulator. It is available on
                 Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, Linux and other Unix X11 systems.
Terminology    - enhanced terminal supportive of multimedia 
                 and text manipulation for X11 and Linux framebuffer
tilda          - A drop down terminal
wterm          - It is a fork of rxvt, designed to be lightweight, but still
                 full of features
xterm          - default terminal for the X Window System
Yakuake        - (Yet Another Kuake), a dropdown terminal for KDE
```

Comment: Most comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 10):

Start another instance of whatever terminal is it you want to run:

```
xterm -hold -e 'apropos editor' &
```

Note the `-hold`. Most terminals will exit after running the command you feed them. There are already a dozen or so questions about this on the site:

- [How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes commands in them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)
- [How to run a script without closing the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal)

An alternative to that is to use an application which needs to be exited. `nano` will stay open on its own. If you're just outputting to screen, you could pipe it into `less`:

```
xterm -e 'apropos editor | less' &
```

That said, in your case (as the other two have said) it does seem easier that you just open another terminal and run your command.

Comment: Can I use `gnome-terminal` instead of `xterm` then How to?

Comment: I'm curious about how to do this with xfce4-terminal (xfce4-terminal opens a new process, while xterm doesn't—in my case, I actually don't want a new process).

Answer (score 5):

1. Open two terminals.
2. Identifying each terminal with `tty` command.
3. Supposing they identified with `/dev/pts/0` and `/dev/pts/1`.
4. In terminal pts/0 redirecting stdout to pts/1 with `exec` command: `exec 1>/dev/pts/1`
5. Now every command stdout output from pts/0 terminal is displaying in pts/1.
6. Redirecting back stdout with command: `exec 1>/dev/pts/0`
7. Now pts/0 stdout working as before.

Answer (score 5):

After Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, you may want to switch from `-e` to `--`, i.e. `gnome-terminal -e` to `gnome-terminal --` because `-e` and `-x` are both deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `-e` option to gnome-terminal as follows:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c propose editor'
```

Here `sh` is the shell that gnome-terminal opens. Note that this will exit the terminal as soon as the command has terminated. Refer to [the manual page for gnome-terminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) for more.

Comment: How to hold new opened terminal, which is exiting after command finished/terminated?

Answer (score 1):

Here goes my 50 cents with Terminator:

```
terminator -x "script.sh; bash"
```

This also works, but I can't tell you the difference:

```
terminator -e "script.sh; bash"
```

Note that script could also be a command.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

So I know this is like 7 years late, but for anyone else seeing this it should still be helpful. I was having this exact problem too but found a solution that I think is better than what anyone else has suggested.

Per `man gnome-terminal` you can just execute `gnome-terminal -- sh -c '<your command>'`

The `-- sh` allows it to run actual scripts instead of applications, so it would be just like typing it into a normal window. The only thing to note about this solution though is that the terminal will quit after the command is done executing.

Hope this helps!