# alias nested string

Tags: bash, alias

I have an `alias` for `youtube_dl` which adds some arguments in my `.bashrc` file. I want to run this in a separate terminal similar to how it is done [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window). The problem is that this takes a string as input.

my current alias:

```
alias youtube-dl="youtube-dl -ci --restrict-filenames -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s'"
```

how I want the new alias to look like:

```
alias youtube-dl='gnome-terminal -e "youtube-dl -ci --restrict-filenames -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s'"'
```

The problem is, however, that now the `'`-strings are interpreted as two separate strings. In addition, I am now unable to add the url as an argument. How do I circumvent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could mess around with quotes and escaping, but I prefer to look for ways to reduce the quoting levels. For example, you could use [`gnome-terminal -x`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) instead:

```
-e, --command=STRING
         Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal.

-x, --execute
         Execute  the  remainder  of  the  command  line  inside   the
         terminal.
```

So,

```
gnome-terminal -e "youtube-dl -ci --restrict-filenames -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s'"
```

Becomes:

```
gnome-terminal -x youtube-dl -ci --restrict-filenames -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

Shaving off one layer of quotes. And the alias would be:

```
alias youtube-dl='gnome-terminal -x youtube-dl -ci --restrict-filenames -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s"'
```

---

Or you could use a function:

```
youtube-dl()
{
    gnome-terminal -x youtube-dl -ci --restrict-filenames -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' "$@"
}
```

Comment: +1 for the function. That was my first thought, using a function.

Comment: Should take advantage of `export -f youtube-dl` after the function definition.