# How to write a shell script that runs commands in separate terminals?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've never written a script before, and I need help with my first one.

I have 3 commands, that need to run in order, in separate windows.

How do i write a script that I can execute, that runs command one, command two, and command three, in order, in separate windows?

I have tried making sense out of other posts, but haven't had any luck

Answer (score 4):

You can do it just by calling three instances of your terminal emulator and telling them to stay open with `exec bash`

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
mate-terminal -x bash -c 'uname -r; exec bash'
mate-terminal -x bash -c 'uname -m; exec bash'
mate-terminal -x bash -c 'uname -s; exec bash'
```

The first terminal pops up with `4.4.0-42-generic` second one with `x86_64`, third one with `Linux`...

If you're using vanilla Ubuntu, then replace `mate-terminal` with `gnome-terminal` or whatever app you use. Replace `uname -[rms]` with your commands. You may find you need to use `-e` and not `-x` for gnome-terminal.

Help from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485007/527764) posted by [Chaos](https://askubuntu.com/users/185729/chaos)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the commands are  command_1, command_2 .. command_n. Then do the following

(You can also use `terminal`, or `konsole`, or `gnome-terminal`, instead of `xterm`, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the) ).

> ```
>  $ xterm -e command_1
>  $ xterm -e command_2
>  .
>  .
>  $ xterm -e command_n
> ```