# Error while running a command in a new gnome-terminal window or tab

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

I found through [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window) that using `-e` (deprecated) or `--` options I can run a command in a new terminal window. Or yet `-x` to do it in a new tab.

However i'm having troubles to do it in my raw *18.04 Bionic Beaver LTS Ubuntu*. The new window / tab is opened, but with the follow error message:

[image]

I made a quick research but didn't find how to solve this.
Any clue is wellcome! Thanks

Comment: I am running 18.04 and the following command opened in a new terminal for me without any errors, What is the command you tried to run that caused the error?                                    $gnome-terminal -- ls -al

Comment: Actually `ls` command is the only one is running correctly. Even if I use some option in it, or choose another command (as `cd` for exemple) it crashes.

Comment: I get the same error but only using cd and -- without any command after it.  All other commands worked for me.  I think because the new window doesn't have a starting present working directory to work on with the cd command or if it supplied with no arguments at all it just fails.  What other commands didn't work for you?

Comment: "Or yet -x to do it in a new tab." – `-e` versus `-x` has absolutely nothing to do with window versus tab.

Comment: Maybe show us the entire command line that you execute and gives this error?

Comment: It's happening with pretty much any command. `gnome-terminal -- "cd ~/Documents"` for example.