# 'Right way' to open new terminal from (bash) script?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

So i need to open a new terminal from a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script (and then run some remote ssh commands through that - this is nice as I will be able to see everything that goes on, on the remote servers). I tried `xterm` but it seems not installed (so not so nice an option that users have to install something first).

So is there no 'independent' way to do this (writing 'gnome-terminal' in script does look very specific) ?

Ideally the spawned terminal could be closed/killed off if the 'owner script' got stopped.

Comment: On my system, `gnome-terminal-wrapper` is an `alternative` for the more widely known `x-terminal-emulator`. See `/etc/alternatives`. So I suggest you use `x-terminal-emulator` which will work just as well, and is compliant with more Unix systems than just `Ubuntu`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run command on another(new) terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window)