# How to run python commands in a new terminal window

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

I am learning django. I am stuck with this problem.

So basically, I have designed a form (template) in HTML that takes a text file as input and generates a voiceover of that text file. I am using `espeak` for it in the backend. So, when a user uploads a file, this command `espeak -ven+m1 -f sample.txt` where `sample.txt` is the name of the uploaded file should run in a new terminal window.

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPxdy.png)

As you can see in the above image this is what I want to achieve.

```
espeak -ven+m1 -f sample.txt
```

I want to print the above line in a new terminal window.

Here, `sample.txt` is the name of the text file. I want to achieve this by the python program instead of doing it manually.

As I already said I am new to django and some help will be appreciated.

Edit:
I tried to run this command

```
subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '--', f"espeak -ven+m1 -f {uploaded_file.name}"])
```

But the output I am getting is this

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process “espeak -ven+m1 -f sample.txt” (No such file or directory)
```

[new shell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBCR4.png)

Also please note that `Run a custom command instead of my shell` checkbox is **untick**

Comment: Hello. Please do not have pictures of text. Include the text in the body of the question.

Comment: @David Done. Actually I put that picture to make the problem clearer.

Comment: What you should do is use `subprocess.run` or similar to run `gnome-terminal -x espeak ...`, instead of using `print()` to just show the command you're running.

Comment: Terminology: with "shell", you mean a new terminal window? Perhaps you can rather have a dialog of your program print these commands in a separate window?

Comment: @vanadium I have made corrections. Perhaps it is clear now.

Comment: Is "sample.txt" existing in the directory where the process is launched?

Comment: @vanadium I have placed it in my home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this command to open a new terminal and run your command in it:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "python3; bash"
```

Here `python3` is the command I am running, you can replace it with your command:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "espeak -ven+m1 -f sample.txt; bash"
```

Now to sum up everything, use this code in your python program:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["gnome-terminal", "-x", "sh", "-c", "espeak -ven+m1 -f sample.txt; bash"])
```

Note: If you're using any other terminal emulator, then you must replace `gnome-terminal` with your emulator.

For more info, please visit this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window)