# Custom keyboard shortcut to lauch a terminal and run a command without exit in the end

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I want to create a shortcut to run a command with keyboard shortcut But when I press "alt+ctrl+a" terminal open and immediately close.

Please help me to edit below command for prevent from close after ran it.

`gnome-terminal  -e "vnstat -ru -i wlan0 -h"`

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155955/70524

Comment: The answer is awesome! Please don't delete it.

Comment: Which answer are you talking of?

Comment: @muru chaos answer. Although I don't know, I'm just a newbie.

Comment: That is pretty much what this two year old answer is: http://askubuntu.com/a/176249/158442 Anyway, this probably won't get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this command instead:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'vnstat -ru -i wlan0 -h; exec bash'"
```

The `exec bash` part at the end causes to start a `bash` that replaces the current shell (also a `bash`).

Answer (score -1):

create a keyboard shortcut with the following command :  gnome-terminal  . Thats it.

Comment: Also wants run a command

Comment: What do you mean?   This command "gnome-terminal" opens your terminal.

Comment: Read the OP's question. He wants open a terminal and run his command altogether not just open terminal alone.