# bashcript that opens another bashscript

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a script that opens terminal and list directories. My problem is that the second terminal ls the files but disapears in a flash. how can i make it not disappear? i have tried sleep but not working.

Comment: This might be helpful to you... http://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Put a read statement at the end of the script.

```
read -p "Press Enter to quit" oDummy
```

Comment: gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ls -l ../Documents "