# Terminal profile registering aliases

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, alias

I'm trying to use the gnome-terminal profiles to cd to a given directory and register some aliases just after the terminal opens.

I have created a script:

**~/Document/project1/ops-setup.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
alias up='docker-compose up -d'
alias down='docker-compose stop'
...
```

Then a new gnome-terminal **Project 1** profile running the following as "custom command"

```
bash -c "cd ~/Document/project1;. ./ops-setup.sh"
```

I can see my script launched when I open the terminal with this profile, the terminal remains opened but it does not leave the prompt.

> The child process exited normally with status 0.

I tried to add a bash run after it so the prompt remains

```
bash -c "cd ~/Document/project1;. ./ops-setup.sh";bash
```

but no alias registered (I guess that's because it is a new process)

I also tried `--init-file`

```
bash --init-file <(echo "cd ~/Document/project1;. ./ops-setup.sh")
```

but bash complains

> bash: cd ~/Document/project1;. ./ops-setup.sh): No such file or directory

How can I keep my aliases registered for this **Project 1** profile ?

---

There are [multiple ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal) to keep the terminal opened after running scripts and I that's not my issue. I'm really talking about keeping aliases registered

Comment: Please explain me how this is a duplicate. I explicitly tell that I'm not trying to run a script without closing the terminal. My issue was not there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following @dessert suggestion using a script that includes `bashrc` as `init-file`, here is was I did:

**~/Document/project1/bash-wrapper.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT_PATH=`dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`   
cd $PROJECT_PATH

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi

source $PROJECT_PATH/ops-setup.sh
```

And defined this custom command in the gnome-terminal profile:

```
bash --init-file ~/Documents/project1/bash-wrapper.sh
```

Comment: Wow, now I'm getting delete votes here ? For real ? Any explanation ? Is it a really bad answer ?